# How does cabal determine where to install packages globally (windows)?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform, cabal-install

I have installed haskell into a custom location, which I have in my PATH:

```
C:\platforms\haskell\2014.2.0.0\bin
```

However, when I install a package globally, I get this:

```
Installing executable(s) in C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin
Warning: The directory C:\Program Files\Haskell\bin is not in the system
```

Where is it getting this path from, and how can I control where haskell will install packages globally? I would prefer they were installed in either the haskell install directory or my user profile somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Your cabal configuration has a block labeled `install-dirs global` which gives the directories to use for global installations. I'm not sure where this file sits on Windows, but in Linux, it is in `~/.cabal/config`; so perhaps you can poke around in your profile's local settings directory for a directory named `cabal` or similar that contains a `config` file in it.

Comment: On my Windows 8 machine, the config file is located at `C:\Users\Orchid\AppData\Roaming\cabal\config`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what [MathematicalOrchid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1006010/mathematicalorchid) already mentioned, from the [Cabal-Install](https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal-Install) wiki page:

> You can edit the cabal configuration file to set defaults, for *nix
>   based systems this is:
>
> ~/.cabal/config
>
> The config file on a Windows system is
>
> %appdata%\cabal\config